# Можно ли по грамотности судить о человеке?

Tags: общие-вопросы

Когда вижу, что человек пишет безграмотно, у меня складывается о нем определенное мнение как о некультурной, неинтеллектуальном и т.д. И чем менее он грамотный, тем это мнение сильнее.
Как вы думаете, можно ли по уровню грамотности судить о культурном уровне человека?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут на самом деле нужно сперва разобраться, а что такое грамотность в вашем понимании? Не знаю конечно, но думаю, составлять мнение о человеке потому, как грамотно он пишет вам приходится в основном в интернете. Способ оценки значимости интернет-сообщения по грамотности вполне приемлем. В конце концов оценить интеллект по более точным признакам; манерам, выражению лица, точности речи, у нас возможности нет, а как-то представить себе человека необходимо. Недостатков у подобного восприятия два:
Первый - в рунете довольно много умных и интеллектуальных людей, для которых русский не является родным языком.
Второй - на некоторых сайтах принято общаться на особом сленге, который назовём, скажем, "разговорным письмом". Этот стиль письменной речи возник сравнительно недавно, когда появилась возможность быстро обмениваться текстовыми сообщениями (SMS, чаты). Основные черты этого стиля: крайне упрощённая пунктуация (вплоть до полного отсутствия), смайлы, короткие резаные фразы, сокращение длинных слов (сек, вместо секунда; инфа вместо информация и т.п.). Следовательно по сообщениям без частых и грубых орфографических ошибок, написанных в этом стиле, делать выводы тоже не стоит.

В целом, грамотность письменной речи, довольно достоверный показатель интеллектуального развития человека, НО! только в том случае, когда сам пишущий стремится написать текст грамотно. Нарочитая безграмотность ничего об интеллекте пишущего нам рассказать не сможет. В любом случае, для оценки интеллектуального уровня советую больше внимания обращать на лексику и используемые речевые конструкции, чем на соблюдение орфограмм, так вы получите более объективное представление о человеке.

Comment: Я согласна с ответом, а насчет сленга... Знаете, когда художник изучил классическую школу живописи в Академии Художеств, он может позволить себе примитивизм. Так же и тут. Если ты пишешь грамотно, то можешь позволить себе и "олбанский", а если собственное имя не можешь написать без ошибок, то... )))

Comment: @Fuchoin Kazuki, под сленгом я имею в виде в большей степени не устаревшие "олбанский" или "кащенитский", а стиль характерный для общения в соц. сетях, SMS или Скайпе. Как правило запятые там ставят, только если без них фраза не понятна вовсе, из остальных знаков могут поставить только "?". Понятно, что данный стиль не отменяет орфографию, но пунктуация в этом случае практически полностью игнорируется в пользу скорости отправки сообщений.

Answer (score 4):

Я тоже какое-то время думала, что грамотность на письме и в общении  - это показатель общей культуры человека. Но сейчас уверена, что это не так.

Приходилось сталкиваться с людьми, которые пишут без ошибок и говорят,аж заслушаешься,а при более близком общении оказывалось, что человечек "с червоточинкой". Может жутко повести себя в несложной конфликтной ситуации с другими людьми, например, в магазине, кафе или еще где-нибудь. Вот тут вся "культура" видна.

А есть среди моих знакомых люди, которые "молоко" могут с тремя "а" написать, но при этом настолько душевные люди, что я готова простить им любые ошибки. Она из них - моя родственница. Да, пишет с ошибками, но это ей совершенно не мешает (не знаю, правда, как) занимать хорошую должность. Она более приспособлена к жизни, чем я, хоть и моложе. Есть у нее какая-то житейская мудрость. Она прекрасная мама, добрый, веселый человечек.
Еще в сети общаюсь с подругой, у которой проблемы со слухом. Думаю, что ее ошибки связаны именно со здоровьем. Она в своих сообщениях никогда никого не осудит, всегда поддержит, а это намного важнее, чем правильно и изящно написанный бездушный текст.

Comment: Письма прабабушки, которая закончила только начальную школу, мы храним как семейную реликвию. Ошибки есть, но так интересно она пишет.

Answer (score 3):

Для ответа на поставленный вопрос - о культурном уровне человека - прежде всего необходимо разобраться в понятиях. Что есть грамотность и культурность? Я пыталась выяснить, что пользователи этого сайта вкладывают в понятие "культурный человек". К сожалению, удовлетворяющего меня ответа я не получила.

В общем и целом, исходя из жизненного опыта, я могу сделать вывод, что обычно люди вкладывают в эти понятия (очень-очень грубо): культурный=хорошо, некультурный =плохо.

То же я могу отнести и к понятию грамотности. Но в отношении грамотности нужно сделать еще одно уточнение: речь идет всего лишь о грамматике, ведь так? (О чём еще может идти речь на этом сайте...)

Исходя из этого, я переформулирую изначальный вопрос, как я его понимаю: можете ли вы считать хорошим человеком того, кто пишет с ошибками?

Мой ответ такой. Если это текст официальный, то ошибки вызывают во мне раздражение, и чем выше уровень организации, от имени которой написано письмо, тем это раздражение сильнее. Кого они там понабрали к себе на работу? Шарашкина контора!

Однако судить о личности человека по грамматическим ошибкам, тем более в интернете, нельзя.

[@Марк Из](/users/1067/%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7) привел пример интернетного стиля общения, когда ошибки делаются нарочно. В самом деле, есть сайты, где писать по всем правилам просто неприлично. Это выглядит на общем фоне вызывающе и создает не самый благоприятный образ пишущего в глазах других пользователей. Такое явление в интернете очень распространено, оно позволяет частично отсеивать "несвоих".

[@Людмила](/users/247/%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0) привела пример с бабушкой. Моя бабушка тоже была не шибко грамотной, писала как слышала, но ни в коем случае не могу назвать ее бескультурной. Многим деятелям культуры на нее бы равняться.

Не могу также не сказать в защиту тех, кто не обладает даром красноречия. Люди с техническим и математическим складом ума, привыкшие работать со схемами, цифрами, знаками подчас испытывают затруднения в формулировании своих мыслей общечеловеческим языком.

Comment: > Люди с техническим и математическим
> складом ума, привыкшие работать со
> схемами, цифрами, знаками подчас
> испытывают затруднения в
> формулировании своих мыслей
> общечеловеческим языком.

Мне приходилось общаться с подобными людьми, в том числе и в интернете. Воспринимать таких людей сложно скорей даже из-за заумности речи. Стремление к точности в такой речи ведёт к обилию причастных и деепричастных оборотов, большому числу терминов и пр., что в целом восприятие затрудняет. В речи же неграмотного человека, деепричастных оборотов не бывает вовсе, даже там где без них фраза менее понятна

Answer (score 2):

Культурный уровень, конечно, включает в себя орфографическую и пунктуационную грамотность, но, кроме того, отражает степень приобщения к общемировым духовным ценностям, степень овладения другими знаниями, умениями, навыками, идеями, накопленными человечеством за весь период своей истории, воспитанность, т. е. умение вести себя в обществе, поэтому судить о человеке только по уровню грамотности несправедливо. Моя бабушка долго была почти неграмотна, грамоте обучилась во взрослом состоянии,но читать очень любила, знала больше, чем некоторые с высшим образованием, обладала высокой культурой общения, так что некультурной её никак не назовёшь. То, что человек пишет неграмотно, конечно, слегка подрывает его авторитет, но не моё к нему отношение, отношение у меня меняется, когда человек ведёт себя некультурно, по-хамски, тогда даже при его безукоризненной грамотности и больших знаниях я его не уважаю. А исправить грамотность сейчас легко, надо только захотеть.

Answer (score 1):

Согласна с автором. Думаю, речь идёт о написании с откровенными ошибками «впринципи, ненадо, говориш» и тд. «Молодёжный сленг», о котором было упомянуто в комментариях выше, никакого отношения к безграмотности не имеет - это другое. И это видно.

Культурный человек и душевный человек - это разные вещи. «Культурный» не равно «душевный». Поэтому эти ассоциации в предыдущих комментариях тоже вызвали у меня удивление. Автор говорил про образованность, грамотность, в какой-то степени(!) об умственных способностях человека.

По жизненному опыту могу сказать - да, люди, совершающие откровенные ошибки в письменной речи, действительно малообразованные. Но не все. Есть исключения.

Answer (score 0):

Я знаю человека, который получил золотую медаль по окончании школы в советское время. Ленинский степендиат в университете. Даже докторскую защитил. Но у него по нынешним критериям DSM-5 - НРЛ (нарциссическое расстройство личности). НРЛ не лечится. Измучил всех жён, любовниц, детей! На Ютубе можете про людей с НРЛ и других психопатов посмотреть. Страшные люди, коих всё больше становится вокруг нас с каждым годом! И женщины такие бывают! Реже, но бывают.
Я к чему... он очень грамотно пишет :)